# Rails Validations and custom error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm having an issue with Validations, if I use the following syntax all is well (no failures).

```
validates :title, uniqueness: true
```

However if I change it to this, I get a failure.

```
validates :title, uniqueness: {message: 'Title must be unique'}
```

Here is the test for completeness:

```
test "product is not valid without a unique title " do
  product = Product.new( title: products(:ruby).title,
  description: "yyy",
  price: 1,
  image_url: "fred.gif" )

  assert !product.save
  assert_equal "has already been taken", product.errors['title'].join('; ')
end
```

I have a fixture that adds the book title for the Ruby product etc.

As I understand it the two validations should be the same, just that one gives a custom error message. This is the error I get when using the custom message.

1) Failure:
test_product_is_not_valid_without_a_unique_title_(ProductTest)
<"has already been taken"> expected but was
<"Title must be unique">.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
assert_equal "has already been taken", product.errors['title'].join('; ')
```

you expect to see "has already been taken" in the errors hash, but you've overridden this message with your custom message. Test shows that your custom message appears as it should. Why do you still expect the default message? You have to expect `Title must be unique`.

**TIP** Don't supply the name of your field in your custom message. Rails will handle it automatically when generating errors by, say, `product.errors.full_messages` ("must be unique" would be enough).

Comment: Its not that I don't expect to see the custom message, I don't expect a message at all unless I try to insert a duplicate title? Thanks for the tip on not putting in the field name ;)

Comment: Aren't your testing DB already filled with your fixtures? Looks like you're trying to create a record with existing title.

Comment: Yes but shouldn't I be getting the failure regardless of wether I use a custom message. validates :title, uniqueness: true should still trigger a failure when I run the test. As you say the fixture will load the DB  with test data, so either validates clause should trigger the failure. Unless I'm missing something ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't get errors. Using `validates :title, uniqueness: true` + `assert_equal "has already been taken", product.errors['title'].join('; ')` in your test leads your test to passing as your record **still isn't saved**, but with `uniqueness: true` your expectation for error matches the error you get. You must be confused about this "negative" expectation. *Your test passes when your record fails to save itself*. But record itself doesn't complain about this failure. It just only returns `false` as the result of `save` (and it's checked via `assert !product.save` -- note the `!`).

Comment: Ok I get it now, the whole issue was nothing to do with the test failing, just that the message was different to the one expected. I removed the assert and using the custom message validation the test ran with 0 failures. Still not sure I agree this should have caused a failure message, the test behaved as expected in both cases I just overrode the error message in one of them. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Once more to grasp it eventually: before running your tests your DB is filled with records based on your fixtures. Then you're trying to save object with existing title (because you set title for it from fixtures). Saving fails, `assert !product.save` passes (you negate the result of `save` by the `!` and `false` becomes `true`. So you actually call `assert !false` or `assert true`). Then it comes to message testing. This part you've already cracked. Just a note: `save` checks validations which includes setting of errors. You can check them after that and you do it by `assert_equal`.